# SQL import command

Tags: mysql, import

I am having trouble writing an import query in multiple tables. Here is my original data in csv file.

```
Original Table `survey.csv`

id   |date      |race   |age   |other data    
--------------------------------------------
001  |2022-02-05|White  |32    |data123
002  |2022-01-16|Asian  |28    |data234
003  |2022-01-25|Asian  |24    |data462
004  |2022-01-25|Black  |28    |data346
005  |2022-03-25|Other  |28    |data346
```

I know the import script for the table is

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '~/Documents/survey.csv' 
INTO TABLE survey 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

but I am redesigning the table into following three

```
---race--- 

id   |short_name
--------------------
1    |White
2    |Black
3    |Asian
4    |Other

---imported `survey` table---

id   |date      |race_id|age   
-------------------------------
001  |2022-02-05|1      |32    
002  |2022-01-16|3      |28    
003  |2022-01-25|3      |24    
004  |2022-01-25|2      |28    
005  |2022-03-25|4      |28    


---data---

id   |other data 
-----------------
001  |data123
002  |data234
003  |data462
004  |data346
005  |data346
```

What is a good script to import the data in proper way? I tried several way and I wasn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

The LOAD DATA INFILE command only supports importing to a single table per command. You can't split up the data into multiple tables in a single call to that command.

One solution is that you could import the data to a single table, then run a series of steps to refactor the data into multiple tables.

A different solution is that you split up the file into three different CSV files, then import each one to the respective table.

A third solution would be for you to write a custom program to import the data row by row, splitting as needed, or re-using entries created by earlier rows. As far as I know, there is no tool that does this automatically. You would have to write it yourself. Pretty much every programming language has a function for reading a CSV file and looping over its entries. Then it's up to you to write the logic to separate the fields that go into each table.